# embed a torus in $\mathbb{R}P^3$

Tags: general-topology

How can I embed a torus in $\mathbb{R}P^3$?
I know how to embed a 4 dimensional torus ($S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$) in $\mathbb{R}^4$ But how to embed a 4 dimensional torus in $\mathbb{R}^4/\sim$, where $x\sim \lambda x$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$?
Is this possible for every 4 dimensional torus (or does the torus has to have another dimension, which?) and if not: Which characteristics does the torus has to have?

Comment: $S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$ is three-dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no embedding $f:S^1\times S^1\times S^1\to\mathbb RP^3$. By the [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) for manifolds, any such $f$ would be an open map, so the image would have to be open. Since $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$ is compact, the image would also have to be closed. Since $\mathbb RP^3$ is connected, this would mean that $f$ is surjective. But a bijective open map is a homeomorphism, which is impossible because $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$ and $\mathbb RP^3$ are not homeomorphic.

You can however embed $S^1\times S^1$ into $\mathbb RP^3$. Any point in $\mathbb RP^3$ has a neighborhood $U$, homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$. Compose such a homeomorphism with an embedding of $S^1\times S^1$ into $\mathbb R^3$ and you're done.

Comment: thank you for you answer! :)

Comment: I have a question to the neighborhood. We don't have a specific topology for the space $\mathbb{R}P^3$, right? So how is the neighborhood "defined"?

Comment: @user3766553: yes, $\mathbb RP^3$ does have a standard topological structure, namely, it is the quotient space of $\mathbb R^4\setminus\{0\}$ with respect to the equivalence relation you mention in your question. Furthermore, it is a topological manifold with respect to this structure.